# Given ~(A->B) how would I reach the conclusion of A&~B

Tags: logic, natural-deduction

I'm pretty stuck on this question and not sure how to be able to derive the conclusion from the premise. Any help would be appreciated!

My work so far:

[image: 1]

Comment: Did you try using a truth table?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  $A\implies B$ is equivalent to $\lnot A\lor B$

Comment: Thank you for responding! No I haven't used a truth table, I'll make one. What should I be looking for in a truth table that could help me with this question? I'm taking an introductory course to logic so I'm still trying to figure things out.

Comment: Change your implication into a or. Then use de Morgan's law.

Comment: What had you try, and what axioms and rules you can use for the derivation?

Comment: I added an image of my work so far, my goal was to try and get A and ~B so that I could do a conjunction introduction with the two but I'm a little stuck on how to get A. Should I restart do a assumption of ~(A&~B) and do a negation elimination? I can only use the SD rules

Comment: It is not a good idea to post images as they are not always readable.  For instance, imgur is blocked from my location.

Answer (score 1):

To reach $A\&\lnot B$, prove $A$ and $\lnot B$ separately, then use *conjunction introduction*.  To prove them use a reduction to absurdity and an indirect proof, respectively.  Both require deriving a contradiction from an assumption, and the only other thing to contradict is the premise, which is a negation of a conditional), so derive that conditional...

The exact rules and format you use will depend on your proof system, but the skeleton will basically be:

$$\def\fitch#1#2{~~~~\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}\fitch{\lnot (A\to B)}{\fitch{\lnot A}{\fitch{A}{~\vdots\\B}\\A\to B\\\bot}\\\lnot\lnot A\\A\\\fitch{B}{\fitch{A}{~\vdots\\B}\\A\to B\\\bot}\\\lnot B\\A\,\&\,\lnot B}$$

Answer (score 1):

In your attempt, you used ($\lor$ Elim) to show $a\to b$, in order to conclude $\lnot b$, which is correct. However, it's unnecessary, we can just assume $a$, then reit $b$, so we have $a\to b$ hold.

Then you assumed $\lnot a$, but stucked on showing that $a\to b$, a hint for this is that once we assume $a$ under $\lnot a$ it's a contradiction, use this and ($\lnot$ Elim) to derive $b$.

The proof looks like the following
$\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}$
$\def\pra#1{\left(#1\right)}$
$$\fitch{1.~\lnot\pra{a\to b}}
{\fitch{2.~\lnot a}
{\fitch{3.~a}
{\fitch{4.~\lnot b}{5.~\lnot a\hspace{5ex}\text{2, R}\\
6.~a\hspace{6.6ex}\text{3, R}}
\\7.~b\hspace{10.3ex}\text{4-6, $\lnot$ E}}
\\
8.~a\to b\hspace{8.9ex}\text{3-7, $\to$ I}\\
9.~\lnot\pra{a\to b}\hspace{4.6ex}\text{1, R}}\\
10.~a\hspace{15.9ex}\text{2-9 $\lnot$ E}\\
\fitch{11.~b}
{
\fitch{12.~a}
{13.~b\hspace{9ex}\text{11, R}}\\
14.~a\to b\hspace{7.6ex}\text{12-13, $\to$ I}\\
15.~\lnot\pra{a\to b}\hspace{3.5ex}\text{1, R}}\\
16.~\lnot b\hspace{14.5ex}\text{11-15, $\lnot$ I}\\
17.~a\land\lnot b\hspace{10.8ex}\text{10,16 $\land$ I}}
$$

Comment: Dude thank you so much man! I was stuck for so long and that was such an easy alternative to my disjunctive elimination, really appreciate the help